# What does the skull icon with the red waves on the Sauron's Army screen mean?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

Here's a picture: [image: Picture of the red skull]

Actually, it'd be helpful to know what they all meant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This icon indicates your currently selected target. If found and scanned, this target will appear on the HUD with this icon, and if you know where the target is through intel, their approximate position will be displayed on the map.

Comment: Oh duh... All I had to do was select another capo to figure that out. I'm kinda dumb like that sometimes. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know the PC controls, but if you go into the map screen, and press RB/R1 (Xbox/PS), it will bring up the legend which tells you what every icon means.

[image: Shadow of Mordor - Map Legend]

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually play on PC (on my tv though, and I'm lazy so forgive me for not taking a proper screen shot), but I'm playing with and Xbox 360 controller.